# Problema para actualizar un array hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buen día, tengo un problema al crear un form_tag que me permita actualizar diversos modelos, estoy usando el method de create para actualizar los modelos, el detalle es que el formulario me envía los parámetros pertenecientes a un arreglo de pagos (payrolls), un renglón (tr) por cada pago. Sin embargo en la consola me arroja el siguiente error:

> Unpermitted parameters: employee_wd_id, employee_wd_attributes

Y tengo la siguiente configuración en el controlador:

```
def payroll_params
  params.permit( 
    payroll: [
      :id, :employee_id, :week_id, :department_id, :dias_trabajados,
      :dias_vacaciones, :faltas, :total_percepciones, :total_retenciones,
      :total_sueldo_bruto, :total_sueldo_neto, :sueldo_fiscal, :pago_impuesto,
      :pago_eps, :tipo_pago_fiscal, :tipo_pago_eps, :created_by, :updated_by,
      employee_wd_attributes: [:id, :jueves, :viernes, :sabado, :domingo, :lunes, :martes, :miercoles],
      employee_wad_attributes: [:id,:importe_ads]
    ]
  )
end
```

En el modelo:

```
class Payroll < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :week
  belongs_to :employee_cw
  has_many   :employee_wad, :dependent=> :destroy 
  has_one    :employee_wd, :dependent=> :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_wad      
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_wd
end
```

Y en la vista uso el siguiente formato (en forma resumida):

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "payrolls", action: "create",method:"post", remote: true) do %>   

  <% @payroll.each do |payroll| %>
    <tr><td>
      <%= text_field_tag("payroll[][employee_wad_attributes][importe_ads]", ad[0]) %>
    </td></tr>
  <% end %>

  <tr><td><%= submit_tag("guardar") %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

En este punto me gustaría mencionar que lo que deseo es un arreglo de importes_ads perteneciente a employee_wad_attributes ya que son aproximadamente 12 conceptos actualmente que debo actualizar y todos son enviados desde la vista de pagos.

En el metodo update:

```
def update
  payroll_params[:payroll].each do |upd_params|
    params_employeewd = {
      :jueves=>upd_params[:jueves],
      :viernes=>upd_params[:viernes],
      :sabado=>upd_params[:sabado],
      :domingo=>upd_params[:domingo],
      :lunes=>upd_params[:lunes],
      :martes=>upd_params[:martes],
      :miercoles=>upd_params[:miercoles]
    }

    params_payroll = {
      :employee_id=>upd_params[:employee_id], 
      :week_id=>upd_params[:week_id], 
      :department_id=>upd_params[:week_id], 
      :dias_trabajados=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :dias_vacaciones=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :faltas=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :total_percepciones=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :total_retenciones=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :total_sueldo_bruto=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :total_sueldo_neto=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :sueldo_fiscal=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :pago_impuesto=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :pago_eps=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :tipo_pago_fiscal=>upd_params[:week_id],
      :tipo_pago_eps=>upd_params[:week_id]
    }

    @employeeWd = EmployeeWd.find(upd_params[:employee_wd_id])
    @employeeWd.update(params_employeewd)

    @payroll = Payroll.find(upd_params[:id])
    @payroll.update(params_payroll)
  end      
end
```

La verdad no se si estoy sacando mal los parámetros o no se, pero ademas de enviarme todos los parámetros no los esta separando si no que los estoy recorriendo en un solo hash, por ejemplo si son 2 renglones cuando el each del método update entra por segunda vez los parámetros van nulos.

primera vez:

> Payroll Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `payrolls`.* FROM `payrolls` WHERE `payrolls`.`id` = 258 LIMIT 1

segunda vez:

> Payroll Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `payrolls`.* FROM `payrolls` WHERE `payrolls`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1

Les agradezco de antemano la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

> Editado:

En los logs me mando esto:

```
Started POST "/companies/1/weeks/169/payrolls?method=post&remote=true" for 200.94.45.34 at 2017-05-27 16:51:29 +0000
Cannot render console from 200.94.45.34! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PayrollsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lQpIAAD45MF7BNPedoTVJ0rxRwSHSlDFD4RHNrPJT44yzYEeGpwWiFuajIZNUBnceRsstrULDbTxyZdiLOA3bA==", "
  payroll"=>[{"id"=>"258", "week_id"=>"169", "department_id"=>"2", "employee_id"=>"1", "employee_wd_attributes"=>{"employee_wd_id"=>"222", "jueves"=>"1",
  "viernes"=>"4", "sabado"=>"1", "domingo"=>"2", "lunes"=>"2", "martes"=>"2", "miercoles"=>"2"}, "dias_trabajados"=>"1.0", "dias_vacaciones"=>"1", "faltas"=>"1",
  "total_sueldo_bruto"=>"169.0", "employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
  {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
  {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
  {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}, "total_percepciones"=>"", "total_retenciones"=>"", "sueldo_fiscal"=>"169.0", "total_sueldo_neto"=>"169.0"
  , "id"=>"259", "week_id"=>"169", "department_id"=>"2", "employee_id"=>"3", "employee_wd_attributes"=>{"employee_wd_id"=>"223", "jueves"=>"1", "viernes"=>"1", "sabado"=>"1", "domingo"=>"1", "lunes"=>"1",
  "martes"=>"1", "miercoles"=>"11"}, "dias_trabajados"=>"1", "dias_vacaciones"=>"1", "faltas"=>"1", "total_sueldo_bruto"=>"11"}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"1"}}, 
  {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"1"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"1"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"1"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
  {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, 
  {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}, 
  "total_percepciones"=>"200.0", "total_retenciones"=>"0.0", "sueldo_fiscal"=>"0.0", "total_sueldo_neto"=>"0.0"}], "commit"=>"guardar", "method"=>"post", "remote"=>"true", "company_id"=>"1", "week_id"=>"169"}
Unpermitted parameter: employee_wd_id
Unpermitted parameter: employee_wd_id
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, commit, method, remote, company_id, week_id
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir los parámetros que recibe el request (los puedes ver en los logs)?

Comment: Ya los agregue @Gerry

Comment: con respecto al primer problema, parece ser un error de dedo (ve mi respuesta); con respecto a tu otro problema, ¿podrías describir con mayor detalle cuál es tu objetivo? Ayudaría mucho que proporcionaras un ejemplo (reducido) del resultado esperado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameters: employee_wd_id, employee_wd_attributes

Tu método `payroll_params` tiene un error en la llave `employee_wd_attributes`, el primer atributo dice `id` en lugar de `:id`; para corregirlo cambia `id` por `:id`:

```
def payroll_params
  params.permit( 
    payroll: [
      # ... otros parámetros
      employee_wd_attributes: [
        :id, :jueves, :viernes, :sabado, :domingo, :lunes, :martes, :miercoles
      ],
      # ... otros parámetros
    ]
  )
 end
```

`employee_wd_attributes` parece no estar generando error, de acuerdo al log que muestras.

---

> ... por ejemplo si son 2 renglones cuando el each del método update
>   entra por segunda vez los parámetros van nulos.

El comportamiento es correcto ya que en el primer ciclo de `payroll_params[:payroll].each` tomas el primer `Hash` del arreglo `payroll`, el cual **sí** cuenta con `id`; acá te muestro ese primer `Hash`:

```
{
  "id"=>"258", 
  "week_id"=>"169", 
  "department_id"=>"2", 
  "employee_id"=>"1", 
  "employee_wd_attributes"=>{
    "employee_wd_id"=>"222", 
    "jueves"=>"1",
    "viernes"=>"4",
    "sabado"=>"1",
    "domingo"=>"2",
    "lunes"=>"2",
    "martes"=>"2", 
    "miercoles"=>"2"
  }, 
  "dias_trabajados"=>"1.0", 
  "dias_vacaciones"=>"1", 
  "faltas"=>"1",
  "total_sueldo_bruto"=>"169.0", 
  "employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}
}
```

Por lo tanto, cuando en tu método `update` ejecutas `@payroll = Payroll.find(upd_params[:id])`, si obtienes resultado.

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero mira el segundo elemento del arreglo `payroll`:

```
{"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}
```

Como podrás notar, **no** cuenta con `id`, por lo tanto, al ejecutar `@payroll = Payroll.find(upd_params[:id])` obtienes in `id` con `NULL`; de hecho los siguientes 11 elementos del arreglo son iguales.

No sé cuál es el uso de esos elementos, así que revisa si es correcto que se estén enviando y, en caso que así sea, que estén anidados correctamente en la forma que los envía.

Acá te dejo los parámetros con un formato más amigable, el cual te permitirá revisar con mayor claridad cada item que recibes en `params`:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"lQpIAAD45MF7BNPedoTVJ0rxRwSHSlDFD4RHNrPJT44yzYEeGpwWiFuajIZNUBnceRsstrULDbTxyZdiLOA3bA==", 
  "payroll"=>
  [
    {
      "id"=>"258", 
      "week_id"=>"169", 
      "department_id"=>"2", 
      "employee_id"=>"1", 
      "employee_wd_attributes"=>{
        "employee_wd_id"=>"222", 
        "jueves"=>"1",
        "viernes"=>"4",
        "sabado"=>"1",
        "domingo"=>"2",
        "lunes"=>"2",
        "martes"=>"2", 
        "miercoles"=>"2"
      }, 
      "dias_trabajados"=>"1.0", 
      "dias_vacaciones"=>"1", 
      "faltas"=>"1",
      "total_sueldo_bruto"=>"169.0", 
      "employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}
    }, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {
      "employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}, 
      "total_percepciones"=>"", 
      "total_retenciones"=>"", 
      "sueldo_fiscal"=>"169.0", 
      "total_sueldo_neto"=>"169.0", 
      "id"=>"259", 
      "week_id"=>"169", 
      "department_id"=>"2", 
      "employee_id"=>"3", 
      "employee_wd_attributes"=>{
        "employee_wd_id"=>"223", 
        "jueves"=>"1", 
        "viernes"=>"1", 
        "sabado"=>"1", 
        "domingo"=>"1", 
        "lunes"=>"1",
        "martes"=>"1", 
        "miercoles"=>"11"
      }, 
      "dias_trabajados"=>"1", 
      "dias_vacaciones"=>"1", 
      "faltas"=>"1", 
      "total_sueldo_bruto"=>"11"
    }, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"1"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"1"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"1"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"1"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}},
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, 
    {"employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}}, 
    {
      "employee_wad_attributes"=>{"importe_ads"=>"0"}, 
      "total_percepciones"=>"200.0", 
      "total_retenciones"=>"0.0", 
      "sueldo_fiscal"=>"0.0", 
      "total_sueldo_neto"=>"0.0"
    }
  ], 
  "commit"=>"guardar", 
  "method"=>"post", 
  "remote"=>"true", 
  "company_id"=>"1", 
  "week_id"=>"169"
}
```

Comment: Es verdad, ya quedo eso, solo que me sigue apareciendo como si solo fuera un hash en lugar de los 2 que son en la prueba que realizo, ademas no se porque pero como estoy sacando los parámetros de los atributos me dice que esta vació, sabes si los estoy sacando bien o debo crear un each por cada atributo para recorrelo y sacar su valor?

Comment: @DanielRomero Revisa la respuesta actualizada, te dará claridad sobre el resultado que obtienes en tus consultas. No sabría decir si estás haciendo la lectura de forma equivocada o el envío envión es incorrecto (a mi parecer es el envío); necesito más información para poder saberlo.

Comment: ya encontré como solucionar el problema aunque no era lo que quería, pero ahora envió esos importe_ads pero con un nombre diferente cada uno, p.e. bono,flete,pension_alimenticia,etc.. De esta forma el hash ya se comporta de forma correcta, ya que como era un arreglo cerraba y abría el hash como quería creo que lo definí mal o no supe crearlo